# How to use homebrew to install specific llvm packages?

Tags: homebrew

I see that there are many packages in the llvm formula.

- clang
- lld
- etc.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/llvm.rb

If I want to selectively install some of these packages, how to do it? I don't see `brew info` says anything about this. Thanks.

```
$ brew info llvm
llvm: stable 7.0.1 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]
Next-gen compiler infrastructure
https://llvm.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.1 (5,351 files, 2.8GB)
  Poured from bottle on 2019-01-09 at 22:15:00
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/llvm.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘
Required: libffi ✔
==> Options
--with-lldb
    Build LLDB debugger
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:
  LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"

llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have llvm first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include"

==> Analytics
install: 18,004 (30 days), 49,463 (90 days), 158,215 (365 days)
install_on_request: 13,554 (30 days), 37,998 (90 days), 122,990 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

Comment: I think the only solution is to fork the llvm formula and to modify it according to your needs.